# Less media queries don't seem to be compiled

Tags: css, less, babeljs

I have a media queries in less file, code:

```
@phoneMin: 0px;
@tabletMin: 768px;
@smallDesktopMin: 992px;
@phoneMax: (@tabletMin - 1);
@tabletMax: (@smallDesktopMin - 1);

@atLeastTablet: ~"only screen and (min-width: @{tabletMin})";
```

When I @import this file into another less file and utilize my media queries like so:

```
.container {
    @media @atLeastTablet {
        margin-top: 160px;
    }
}
```

Not only does the media query just not work, but it also doesn't seem to compile into the resulting css file, which reads like this:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 160px;
}
```

**EDIT** I attempted to run my server and I'm now getting the following error message: "Unexpected token(1:0)" referring to the first character (period) in one of my less files:

```
.blogPost {
^   .logo {

    }
}
```

The error is being thrown during the babel 6 compilation process. Here is the stack trace:

```
at Parser.pp.raise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:510:12)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:265:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:245:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:176:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:158:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:121:19)
```

Comment: Works perfect in the placeground: http://lesscssismore.com/m3fmdv/2, so maybe there is something wrong with your `@import` statement?

Comment: As for your "server" attempt, the error shows that the project is configured to pass Less files to a JS-transpiler, hence the error. I'm afraid we can't help for either problem w/o knowing more details on how exactly you compile that code.

Comment: Why is server in quotes? I was in fact starting a node server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue is in trying to import my less in a subscript vs my webpack entry point. Moving the import here fixed the issue.